# Unable to access the parent class member in base class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, oop

I am using python 3.4 and i am new in object oriented programming and want to access the parent class member in my child class. But it is not accessible. Can anyone help me to get rid of this?

```
# Base class members can be accessed in
# derived class using base class name.

# Parent or super class
class Company:

    def BasicInfo(self):
        self.CompanyName = "ABC Solutions"
        self.Address = "XYZ"

# Inherited or child class
class Employee(Company):
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, Name):
        print("Employee Name:", Name)
        print("Company Name:", self.CompanyName)

def main():
    # Create an object
    emp01 = Employee("John")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The below mentioned code is working but using the same concept, my code is not working, why? Can anyone explain me the reason.

```
class Room:                                                                     

    def __init__(self):                                                         
        self.roomno = 0                                                         
        self.rcap = 0                                                           
        self.rooms = {}                                                         
        self.nog = 10                                                            

    def addRoom(self):                                                          
        self.rcap = input("Please enter room capacity:\n")                      
        self.rooms[self.roomno] = self.rcap                                     

class Booking(Room):                                                            
    def addBooking(self):                                                       
        while int(self.nog) > int(self.rcap):                                   
            print("Guest count exceeds room capacity of: %d" % int(self.rcap))  

x = Booking()
x.addRoom()
x.addBooking()
```

Comment: Where is your super for `class Booking()`

Comment: I am using this code as reference. This is why i asked the question that it this is working fine, then i am getting error in mine code?

Comment: You do execute `addRoom`. In your first example, `BasicInfo` is never executed, so `self.CompanyName` is never initiated, hence the error.

Comment: Your subclassing relationships are a little odd.  Generally, subclassing is understood to represent an "is a" relationship.  For example, `class Car(Vehicle)` would mean that every `Car` is also a `Vehicle`.  That doesn't work for your classes.  It doesn't make sense for every `Employee` to *be* a `Company`.  Rather, an `Employee` *has* a company.  You should be populating a `Employee.company` attribute instead of relying on inheritance.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but this has to be one of the worst misuse of inheritance I've ever seen. Inheritance is a "Is A" relationship, an employee is NOT a company (what you want here is a "has a" relationship - a company "has" employees), and booking is not a room either (ever tried to sleep in a booking ?) - a room _has_ bookings.

Comment: Note that in your code ``Employee`` overrides ``__init__``, whereas in your reference ``Booking`` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to the superclass' `BasicInfo` method:

```
 def __init__(self, Name):
     print("Employee Name:", Name)
     super().BasicInfo()
     # ^^Here^^
     print("Company Name:", self.CompanyName)
```

You can replace `super().BasicInfo()` with a direct reference to the class obviously:

```
Company.BasicInfo(self)
```

---

In your second example, the subclass does not define a `__init__` method, so it would inherit that from parent; as a result, the instance variables would be present in the child class.

Comment: but the code that i refered in my question also doesn't call the constructor of Room class, Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your base class method `BasicInfo` is never getting called. If you call it explicitly either in your child class's `__init__`, it would work

```
class Employee(Company):
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, Name):
        super(Employee, self).BasicInfo()
        print("Employee Name:", Name)
        print("Company Name:", self.CompanyName)
```